# Branchio returns same deep link

Tags: axios, deep-linking, branch.io

Hi how do I get a new deep link url from branchio, it keeps passing same info.

Here is the code I am using:

```
axios.post('https://api2.branch.io/v1/url', {
"branch_key": config.branchio.key,
"tags": ["group"],
"data": {
"$og_title": title,
"$og_description": description,
"$og_image_url": "https://bridgedapp.com/bridged-new-logo-icon.png",
"custom_integer": 1 //type group
}
})
.then(response => {
console.log(response.data.url);
insertNewGroup(response.data.url);
})
.catch(error => {
console.log("deep link error:", error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Link Creation API will generate the same link if you are passing in the same data in the API request body. Only once you update the request body, you'll get an updated link.